# SSH Cert Auth Synology/Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, certificates, synology

i am tying to connect my Synology to my Webserver.
I created all the needed Keyfiles,

the rights of .ssh are 700
the rights of auth_keys 600

the connection is not possible, i get this verbose output.

Is anyone able to help me?

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp **:**
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA **:**
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Connection closed by 79.***.***.***
```

Thank You 
Link to SSH Config
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NZQ7TKh4)

PS: After digging in the Log Files i found this suspicious line:

```
fatal: mm_answer_keyverify: bad signature data blob
```

Comment: Can you show the config file of `sshd_config`. Please make sure that the key is copied properly with any space at the last line of the last character.

Comment: OK Here is my SSHD_Config : [link](http://pastebin.com/NZQ7TKh4)
I copied the key with ssh-copy-id, so this shoud be ok?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem. Synology's DSM seems to be case sensitive with usernames.